# How to display the field "label" in django's builtin password validation errors?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-authentication

I am using Django's builtin authentication class views and need to customize the error message displayed when password validation fails.

For example, in the builtin **[`PasswordResetView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)**, if I try to change my password to **`test`**, the following errors will display in my template:

- new_password2

  - This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
  - This password is too common.

I would like to change **`new_password2`** to **`New Password`**.

Here is the relevant part of my template for the **`PasswordResetView`**:

```
{% extends 'registration/base.html' %}

{% block card_body %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="old_password">
      Old Password:
      {{ form.old_password }}
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="new_password1">
      New Password:
      {{ form.new_password1 }}
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="new_password2">
      Confirm Password:
      {{ form.new_password2 }}
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Change" class="btn float-right login_btn">
  </div>
{% endblock card_body %}
{% block card_footer %}
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
      {{ form.errors }}
    </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock card_footer %}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Supply some dict to the template that will map form field names to labels you want like:

   ```py
   fields_mapping = {
     'old_password': 'Old password',
     'new_password1': 'New password',
     'new_password2': 'Confirm password'
   }
   ```
2. Just manually iterate over errors and use the the mapping dic to convert field names to labels you want:

   ```py
   {% for field_name in form.errors: %}
     {{ fields_mapping[field_name] }}:
     {% for err_message in form.errors[field_name]: %}
       * {{ err_message }}
     {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Customize HTML/CSS there as you want